# Nginx - How to serve static files with upstream model

Tags: django, nginx

I have running my django application in my ubuntu lxc container at 127.0.0.1:8001 with gunicorn and nginx.

This is nginx conf in `host`:

```
upstream django_app  {
      server 10.0.8.100:8001;
}

server {
        listen  80;
        server_name     mysite.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://django_app;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              }
      }
```

And this is nginx conf in `container`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
     }

    location /static {
            alias /opt/static_files/django_app/;
    }

}
```

This configuration is working. I can see my application running from browser, but static files is not loading. I have `404 not found` for each static file in browser.

the path `/opt/static_files/django_app/` is where all static files collected with `collectstatic` command.

I could not find a way to serve static files with upstream.

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you put the static location first!

Comment: @DanielRoseman No, sir. It didn't work. Everything looks fine. But somehow, host cannot reach `/opt/static_files/django_app/` path. which is in container machine.

Answer (score 0):

`/opt/static_files/` should be the same as the `STATIC_ROOT` setting in your `settings.py` django file.

Also, change:

```
location /static {
        alias /opt/static_files/django_app/;
}
```

to:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /opt/static_files/django_app/;
}
```

Comment: it is same as STATIC_ROOT setting. app is working properly without upstream model. The problem is here (i think), host cannot reach to static files under `/opt/static_files/django_app/` folder. which is located in container.